# get url id in a middleware in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-middleware

I'm making a middleware that check the ownership of an tournament.

So in the url, I have :

> http://laravel.dev:8000/tournaments/1/edit

I need to get the "1" in $tournamentId

In the middleware, I only have $request and $closure parameters, so I tried

```
$tournamentId = $request->get("tournaments");
```

and as @Amir Bar says:

```
$tournamentId = $request->tournaments;
```

I checked the routes with

```
php artisan route:list
```

And I get

```
GET|HEAD | tournaments/{tournaments}        | tournaments.show         | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@show      | auth,roles,ownTournament |
DELETE   | tournaments/{tournaments}        | tournaments.destroy      | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@destroy   | auth,roles,ownTournament |
PATCH    | tournaments/{tournaments}        |                          | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@update    | auth,roles,ownTournament |
PUT      | tournaments/{tournaments}        | tournaments.update       | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@update    | auth,roles,ownTournament |
GET|HEAD | tournaments/{tournaments}/edit   | tournaments.edit         | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@edit      | auth,roles,ownTournament |          | auth,roles,ownTournament |
```

but nothing works...

My middleware:

```
class OwnTournament
{
    /**
     * Check the ownership of tournaments
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        dd($request->route());
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Any idea how should I do it???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your route look like:

```
 Route::get('tournaments/{tournamentId}/edit');
```

do this in the middleware:

```
 $tournamentId =  $request->tournamentId
```

if your route is like:

```
Route::resource('name')
```

do this:

```
$tournamentId =  $request->name;
```

you can also do this to get more info about whats happening:

```
dd($request->route()->parameters());
```

Comment: it didn't work :( I use         Route::resource('tournaments', 'TournamentController');
 in my routes.php

Comment: update my question too. dd($request->route()->parameters()); gives me an error.

Comment: what dd($request->route()); give you?

Comment: can you please post your middleware?

Comment: first instruction is dd,is it still empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99024/discussion-between-amir-bar-and-juliatzin-del-toro).

Answer (score 0):

This has been my solution.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $tournaments = $user->tournaments;
        $tournament = null;
        if ($request->tournaments != null || $request->tournamentId != null) {
            $tournament = $request->tournaments;
            if ($tournament != null) {
                if (!$tournaments->contains($tournament)) {
                    return "You don't have privileges to access this resource";
                }
            }
        }
    }


    return $next($request);
}
```

Thing is middleware is called twice, and the first time, it has access to nothing. I don't exactly know why...

So basically, resolved, but without understanding why it happens, so half resolved :(

Thanks @Amir Bar for helping me!